# closure library generated browser events do not have target

Tags: google-closure-library

I am trying to use closure library to build a small app. I am trying to use event delegation with following code:

```
var dom_ = goog.dom.$('targetelementid');
goog.events.listen( dom_, goog.events.EventType.CLICK, function( e ) {
  console.log( e );
}, false);
```

The problem is that when the event is dispatched and handler function is executed the generated object (goog.events.BrowserEvent ) has the target and currentTarget properties set to null. I don't understand why is that.

If I use the regular listener adding (with `addEventListener` ) the event passed to the handler function has the target set correctly.

Any notes on how to use the event delegation pattern in closure library code when there seem to be no target specified in the event object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really the case, the event have target and everything else needed at the moment when it is available in the handler, however after all registered handlers in goog.events are exhausted the event object is disposed (i.e. all its properties are deleted/null-ed) and because the modern web browser console implementations show 'live' view of the objects, the object seem to be empty.

Hint: use 'debugger;' notion in the place where you have dounts to stop JavaScript execution and open the stack in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

try augmenting your code with a scope object (which is what addEventListener does in the background) since the target is irrelevant if "this" is what dispatched the event.

```
var dom_ = goog.dom.$('targetelementid');
goog.events.listen( dom_, goog.events.EventType.CLICK, function( e ) {
  console.log( e );
}, false, this);
```

Notice that "this" at the end.

Comment: This is not the case, in both code snippets the function is executed in the global scope. The problem is that Chrome displays 'live copy' of the objects and closure disposes the Event object once all listeners registered for the event type are executed, thus the target is missing in debug console, it was deleted. Too much optimizations, huh Google? Anyway, in the time of the callback execution the target property is available. I just was not able to see it in debug console. I figured it out eventually by reading the events.js file.